# On the mass basis of the Dirac equation

Tags: mass, field-theory, dirac-equation

The Lagrangian density used to derive the Diract equation is given as follows:

$$\mathcal{L} = \bar{\Psi}(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m)\Psi$$.

which can be shown to give rise to the Dirac equation:

$$i\partial_\mu\gamma^\mu \Psi - m\Psi =0$$

Then I came across the following claim that asserts that it is useful to write the Dirac equation using the so called mass basis:

[image]

I'm having trouble understanding the meaning of the last equation, in particular how does $\bar{\Psi} = {\Psi}^\star \gamma_0$? Also how does one change basis for the Dirac equation in general?

Comment: I suspect that $\Psi^\ast \equiv \Psi^\dagger$. This means that $\overline{\Psi}=\Psi^\dagger \gamma_0$ is just the definition of $\overline{\Psi}$. To change basis in general you just have to find different representations of the $\gamma$ matrices : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices .

Comment: The definition of the [Dirac adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_adjoint)   of a spinor  $\psi$ is $$ \overline{\psi} = \psi^{\dagger} \gamma^0. $$

Answer (score 2):

1. $\overline{\Psi} = \Psi^\dagger \gamma^0$ is the definition of $\overline{\Psi}$; this is important because $\Psi^\dagger \Psi$ is not a Lorentz scalar.
2. A change of basis proceeds as usual from elementary linear algebra.  Given a COB matrix $N$, spinors transform via $\Psi \mapsto N\Psi$ and matrices via $M \mapsto N M N^{-1}$.

Comment: What is $M$ here? An arbitrary matrix?

Comment: @mathripper Yep.  The text you're using appears to have a typo - that $\frac{1}{2}$ should be $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$.